# Java swing not recognized

Tags: java, swing, syntax, joptionpane

I am just starting out in Java but have hit problems in multiple tutorials when it comes to using swing.  This sample code from Java for Dummies threw the following error:

helloapp.java:

```
public class helloapp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        greeter myGreeterObject = new greeter();
        myGreeterObject.sayhello();
    }
}
```

greeter.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class greeter
{
    public void sayhello()
    {
        //System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, 
<<greeter>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

The thrown error was this upon compile:

```
    c:\>javac helloapp.java greeter.java
greeter.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                    ^
greeter.java:8: error: ')' expected
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                                  ^
greeter.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                                   ^
greeter.java:8: error: ';' expected
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                                     ^
greeter.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                                       ^
greeter.java:8: error: ';' expected
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

^
greeter.java:8: error: not a statement
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

               ^
greeter.java:8: error: ';' expected
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, <<greeter
>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                                   ^
8 errors
```

---

This tutorial gave me similar errors which uses swing but frames instead of panes:
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/basics/

The problems occurred the same on a Windows 7 and XP machine, latest JDK and JRE were used and the 32bit version was used for XP and the 64bit on the 7 system.  I did include the environment variables path and can successfully use basic things like System.out.println .  The XP machine has had previous versions of the JDK and JRE but they were unintalled prior.  I have not tried reinstalling the OS but I'm thinking thats not it as the Win7 system has had a fresh install recently and throws the same problem.  No other major progs were running during any of this.  I used notepad for the progs.

I appreciate any help.  I'm not sure what else to do here other than switch languages.  I'm hoping its just something simple and trivial I've overlooked...

Comment: Are you by any chance a Spanish-speaker? When using Java, you need to use the `"` character for quotes.

Comment: <<HelloWorld>> is not the correct syntax to pass the Object. Please follow the following link to know more about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.htmlJOptionPane.................One more thing read Java Documentation for the Swing It's too better and easy with example

Comment: See also [*guillemet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet).

Comment: Sorry, not a Spanish speaker beyond using google translate =).  Thanks for the suggestion on quotes, i had thought those << looked odd. It seems to have narrowed the errors down to one this time: greeter.java:7: error: cannot find symbol. (points to greeter in the above statement). Also I have to ask, if <<>> is wrong for this use, why would it be used in a Java for Dummies book in an early lesson?

Comment: Figured it out, I also had to put greeter in quotes -> "greeter".  I'm still curious why a simpleton book would instruct people to use <<>> though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class greeter
{
    public void sayhello()
    {
        //System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, World!", 
"greeter", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

String should be in  `""` and not `<< >>`

Comment: A wizard you are, worked like a charm.  Any idea why <<>> would have been suggested by the book in the first place?  Maybe it could be correct in some other fashion other than what I was doing?

Comment: no Java does not support that syntax.. book might have some kind of printing mistake.. or was just trying to highlight string for reading purpose..which book is that?

Comment: Java for Dummies '11.  It could be a placeholder but isn't clear, especially since the wording works within the <<>> if changed.  Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

```
<<Hello, World!>>, 
<<greeter>>
```

isn't valid java.  If these are supposed to be strings use:  `"Hello, World"`

if it is a variable just this is sufficient:  `greeter`

Comment: Yup, that was it.  I had to put greeter in quotes too though, otherwise it threw a "cannot find symbol" error on greeter.  I'm quite irritated though that a basic instruction book would have me use << >> knowing full well it was incorrect.  I wonder what other items like that occur throughout the book.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
//System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, <<Hello, World!>>, 
<<greeter>>, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

with

```
//System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, World!", 
greeter, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // greeter is well defined string.
```

In java , Valid string are always quoted using "" except null.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to have narrowed the errors down to one this time:  greeter.java:7: error: cannot find symbol. (points to greeter in the above statement).  

Also I have to ask, if <<>> is wrong for this use, why would it be used in a Java for Dummies book in an early lesson?

Comment: I got it, had to also put greeter in quotes.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2402654, could be possible that <<>> used as notation for place holder in book.